# Copy files in Visual Studio Post-Build event: Access is denied

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, uac, post-build-event

I added some copy commands to my project's post-build events. These should copy some template files to the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen
```

and similar folders.

**All of them fail with an `Access is denied` message.**

I tried all of the following:

- Explicitly set write privileges on folder to my user.
- Took ownership on the folder (it was at `SYSTEM`).
- Started Visual Studio in elevated mode.
- Turned off UAC (User Access Control)

Still same error. **Any ideas?**

**EDIT:** Here's an example:

```
copy /Y $(ProjectDir)MyFile.xaml "$(DevEnvDir)Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\MyFile.xaml"
```

Comment: Show the actual code you're using in the post-build event. Maybe there's an error in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Process Monitor** to see if it is actually a sharing violation; and that is the source of the Access Denied.